# Vb.Net Datagridview Error Handling

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, error-handling

I have a datagridview that seems to be working fine until the user adds a name into the unique name column that already exists.

I am getting this:

System.Data.ConstraintException: Column 'Name' is constrained to be unique. Value 'test' is already present.

Any suggests as to where and how I capture this error and prevent the users from adding another name, case insensitive, to prevent this huge error from coming up?

Thanks!

Comment: I did this and it solved my problem:

Private Sub dgv_DataError(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs) Handles dgv.DataError
 MsgBox(e.Exception.Message)
End Sub

Comment: well... that didn't format well. I caught the error in datagridview1.DataError for those who want to know. You do not do a try/catch though. I displayed the message within that event with e.exception.

Answer (score 1):

Just catch exceptions of type ConstraintException in your code (make sure it's around the bit where you perform the insert). If that exception gets caught, you display some friendly text "The name 'test' already exists. Please choose another name."

Comment: Can you tell me what event I am capturing this on?

Answer (score 0):

Look in your data source's `OnSelected` event, specifically the `Exception` and `ExceptionHandled` properties of the event arguments.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully grasp this. I am creating a datatable as my source that I populate manually. How would I get to the OnSelected event?

Comment: Don't worry about it: I was thinking asp.net, but DataGridView is a winforms control. So this doesn't really apply to you. I'll leave it up rather than deleting it to help anyone else avoid the same mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply handled the [CellValidating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvalidating.aspx) event and check if an item with the same name exits. If it exists, set `e.Cancel` to `True` and set an error message on this row. Example:

```
Private Sub dataGridView1_CellValidating(ByVal sender As Object, _
                                         ByVal e As DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs) _
                                         Handles dataGridView1.CellValidating

    If ExistsItemWithName(e.FormattedValue.ToString) Then
        e.Cancel = True
        Me.dataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).ErrorText = "An item with this name already exists"
    End If
```

End Sub

Note that if you set an `ErrorText` in CellValidating, you should also handle `CellValidating` to set back the `ErrorText` to `String.Empty`.